# Where can I find the list of UDFs in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm searching in Azure SQL database's console for my User Defined Function, which I created as follows

```
CREATE FUNCTION FnSPLIT_RET_INT(...)
```

However, I can't seem to find where it is stored. Pressing the '`Design`' tab in the console I can find only: `Tables`, `Views`, and `Stored Procedures`. And I can not find my `FnSPLIT_RET_INT` function nowhere.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSMS or SSDT/Visual Studio, you can find your function in the Object Explorer by expanding down the tree: {your database} > Programmability > Functions > Scalar-valued functions.

Alternatively, you can find the function name and definition in T-SQL using the sys.objects and sys.sql_modules system views:

```
select o.object_id, o.name, m.definition 
from sys.objects o 
inner join sys.sql_modules m on o.object_id = m.object_id
where o.type = 'FN'
```